# I w'd like to know If there are simple solutions to integrate other CMSs to wordpress

Tags: customization, login, multisite

I w'd like to know If I can Integrate my other web-sites created to my wordpress multisite using the CMSs like

- [Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/) ( [integration discussion](http://www.boonex.com/unity/forums/topic/WordPress-Integration.htm) )
- [Oxwall](http://www.oxwall.org/)
- [status.net](http://status.net/)
- [sharetronix](http://sharetronix.com/sharetronix/)
- [peoplepods](http://peoplepods.net/)
- [yetanotherforum](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/)
- [vidiscript](http://vidiscript.com)
- [Tikiwiki](http://tikiwiki.org)
- [shapado](http://shapado.com) (script, inspired by stackoverflow) ( [seems to integrate with wordpress.com via OpenID](http://shapado.com/questions/want-to-integrate-wordpress-users-with-s) )

These are the Opensource scripts for social networking and micro blogging.I have the websites created with all these scripts for different purposes like social networking and micro blogging .I w'd like to Integrate these websites to my wordpress multi site.So my users need not sign up/sign in for every site and access all of them with single account .

There are some other users of dolphin and shapado who are willing to integrate their site to wordpress .So I have listed all the scripts using for my websites .So this topic may be useful to others who are looking for Integration of the popular Opensource CMSs to wordpress .

Right now we have some SSO plugins which allows us to login using popular logins like facebook,google etc. But these SSO modules are  not available for the above mentioned scripts .How ever the direct Integration is always helpful .

Does any body have Idea on this?

Comment: Could you please re-write your question (and title) more clearly?

Comment: Agree with @tnorthcutt, the question needs to be significantly reworded. Also, please work it in such a way that it would apply more generally and not just solely for your own use case. Also  please avoid abbreviations like *w'd*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration is a topic at large. There are many strategies on how to combine multiple webapplications under one site-design and URL-layout.

This normally means you have to make up your mind first on how to combine and integrate the applications. Normally app exists next to each other sharing a menu, header and a footer.

For security reasons it's important that the different webapplications do not share the same database and webspace. Otherwise things like a security breach in one of the applications can be used to attack the full site.

Some applications even deliver integration modules for wordpress, I once had a gallery app that was able to hook inside my wordpress theme. But integrational work is nothing click-ready so to say, you're bulding a website with multiple apps.

Comment: Thanks !
Could you tell me if there is any way to enable Single sign on between these applications .Or atleast with the major applications like Dolphin ,Tikiwiki and shapado

Comment: I don't know all those three, so I can't answer that questions out of my head. Sorry.